# Object that is visible only at certain light intensity

Tags: visible-light, home-experiment, light-emitting-diodes, luminosity

I have a lux meter, by which we can measure light intensity.

We have one box, in which we inject the light from a hole.

What we want is, if light intensity for e.g. Lux value is between 400 to 450 then only, object inside box should be visible.

Is there any object of this kind in physics world ?

Note: we don't want to use any electric device inside box.

Comment: What should you observe if the light intensity falls outside that range?

Comment: In that case,  if possible then different object should be displayed or nothing specific.